# Куда правильнее встраивать html popup?

Tags: html

Через `ajax`(если кликнули первый раз) подгружаю popup. Куда его лучше встроить чтобы не нагружать броузер - сразу после тега `<body>` или перед закрытием `</body>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перед закрытием, потому-что он вам не понадобится при загрузке страницы, поэтому пусть грузятся другие html элементы

Comment: Если мы встраиваем html в конец документа, то не будет ли броузер перерисовывать (рендерить)  все выше расположенные элементы?

Comment: Нет, js просто вставит в дом нужный элемент